# Accessing a WPF GroupItem text for conversion in a template

Tags: wpf, listbox, templates, grouping

I'm customising the appearance of grouping in a `ListBox`.  In `ListBox.Resources`, I have declared something like (formatting removed):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
          <!-- Group label -->
          <ContentPresenter />
          <!-- Items in group -->
          <ItemsPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The actual group label is not very readable and I'd like to use a value converter to make it more presentable.  However I cannot find a way to obtain this text and convert it.

I figure that a `Binding` would let me use a converter.

I've tried replacing the `ContentPresenter` above with the likes of...

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
```

...and numerous other things, but to no avail.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well isn't that just typical.  I found the answer shortly after posting...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.Name,
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=GroupItem},
  Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

Sometimes just the process of actually *asking* the question draws the answer out of thin air.  In this case looking at the source code of `GroupItem` in *.NET Reflector* did the trick.

Hope someone else finds this edge case useful.  Still, it would be a lot nicer if `GroupItem` exposed a property for this directly.

I'll still award a correct answer to anyone who knows a nicer way of doing this.